# LibreOffice Calc: How to get file path of the current ods document into the cell?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I would like to get current document folder path as a cell value.
I need it for proper relative reference creation used in a function call `OFFSET(INDIRECT(<generated filepath#sheet.cell>))`

I am out of luck with google. I found basic function `ThisComponent.getURL()` that could help.

The nearest solution is via the reference to other file in the same folder with use of function `FORMULA()` over that cell an then using string operations over the result.

I would expect some simple function like `INFO()` but I could not find any.

Thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this function to the macro library:

```vb
Function GetCurrentFolder
    sUrl = ThisComponent.getURL()
    sParts = Split(sUrl, "/")
    ReDim Preserve sParts(0 to UBound(sParts) - 1)
    GetCurrentFolder = Join(sParts, "/")
End Function
```

Then put this in the spreadsheet formula:

```
=GETCURRENTFOLDER()
```

Answer (score 5):

Add this

```
=CELL("filename")
```

to your cell. It's an absolute path, but you could further manipulate it with the standard text functions.

[Documentation reference](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.1/en-GB/text/scalc/01/04060104.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id3155509)

Answer (score 0):

The answer above was close to what I wanted but not quite.  I wanted to also strip the file:/// off of the directory path, so I modified the function above to the following:

```
Function GetCurrentFolder
    sUrl = ThisComponent.getURL()
    sParts = Split(sUrl, "/")
    ReDim Preserve sParts(3 to UBound(sParts) - 1)
    GetCurrentFolder = Join(sParts, "/")
End Function
```

Then you can use the function call like above:

```
=GETCURRENTFOLDER()
```